# scalacheck: define a generator for an infinite stream with some dependence on previous elements

Tags: scalacheck, property-testing

I'm trying to define a `Gen[Stream[A]]` for an infinite (lazily evaluated) stream of `A`s where each element `A` can depend on previous elements.

As a minimal case, we can take `Gen[Stream[Int]]` where the next element is either `+1` or `+2` of the previous element. For reference here is a haskell implementation:

```
increasingInts :: Gen [Int]
increasingInts = arbitrary >>= go
  where
    go seed = do
      inc <- choose (1,2)
      let next = seed + inc
      rest <- go next
      return (next : rest)
```

I have tried `Gen.sequence` on a `Stream[Gen[A]]` but got a stackoverflow. I also tried defining the `Gen` from scratch, but the constructor `gen` for `Gen` is private and works with private methods/types.

This attempt also gives a stackoverflow.

```
  def go(seed: Int): Gen[Stream[Int]] =
    for {
      inc <- Gen.choose(1, 2)
      next = seed + inc
      rest <- Gen.lzy(go(next))
    } yield next #:: rest

  val increasingInts: Gen[Stream[Int]] = go(0)


increasingInts(Gen.Parameters.default, Seed.random()).get foreach println
```

So I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want can be achieved with this:

```scala
val increasingInts = {
  val increments = Gen.choose(1, 2)
  val initialSeed = 0
  for {
    stream <- Gen.infiniteStream(increments)
  } yield stream.scanLeft(initialSeed)(_ + _)
}
```

`.scanLeft` is like a `.foldLeft` but retains the intermediate values, thus giving you another `Stream`.

---

I've written about `scanLeft` here: https://www.scalawilliam.com/most-important-streaming-abstraction/

Comment: Great solution! I didn't need to depend on the previous value after all!